# Make rows in admin grid not clickable with default cursor (not pointer)

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom

So, this is my grid layout

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="custom.name">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\My\Collection\Grid</argument>
            <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">MyGrid</argument>
            <argument name="use_ajax" xsi:type="string">true</argument>
            <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">custom_id</argument>
            <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">DESC</argument>
            <argument name="grid_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/customer/customgrid">
                <param name="_current">1</param>
            </argument>

        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="customer.edit.tab.columnSet">
           ....
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now the rows are clickable, but I want to make them not clickable with  default cursor. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find by myself. You should set rowUrl to empty string like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="customer.test.edit.tab.columnSet">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="path" xsi:type="string"></item>
                    </argument>
            </arguments>
...
```